# How to control number of running worker processes for MongoDB?

Tags: optimization, memory-management, mongodb, configuration, worker-process

Well, as the question simply explains itself, let me clear it up little more.

I am running MongoDB primarily for read-only purposes at back-end. My crons do the writes and they don't really push it hard when they are triggered. Some updates, some new documents etc.

The thing is requests usually do not even hit the application level because of entire page caching handled within MemCached by Nginx. So the application doesn't query database for another hour per page.

But so far as I can see in my process list, there are 21 MongoDB worker processes that are using none of the CPU but reasonably large amount of memory because of the previous queries.

I checked the [configuration settings](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration) and googled around but couldn't find any answer.. So, is there any way to limit those processes or at least to tell MongoDB reduce/empty its memory usage after a while?

Comment: How many connections to do the database do you see when you have 21 workers? There's a rather large per-connection memory footprint so ensuring the maximum amount of connections is always 1 should help you. This is a driver-side setting.

Comment: I had to restart mongod (because of some weird log file access problem) so there are 14 workers at the moment and only 5 connections with no query running. It also says 704mb mapped data and 1.5gb virtual size.

Comment: After all these years, have you find a way to control the number of workers?

Comment: @lepe: I've asked this question directly to the MongoDB guys on a conference and I got the reply; unfortunately you can't control it's internal behaviour. However, that was many years back, things might have changed since then.

Comment: @kirpit: thanks for the update. I guess the answer may be somewhere hidden in their code. If I have time someday, I will give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Workers are using for talking to config server and other replica as well apart from just serving user request. This is documented in [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/ulimit/#resource-utilization).

we can limit `net.maxIncomingConnections` as par recommendation on [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/ulimit/#mongos) page to limit the number of workers processing user request. But this should be used with precaution as setting this number too low and then sending more concurrent calls will result in some calls being queued.